# Add (has_many) association to FactoryGirl.create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I know how to create a has_many associations when defining a Factory:

```
factory :user do
    name "John Doe"
    factory :user_with_posts do
      ignore do
        posts_count 5
      end

      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        create_list(:post, evaluator.posts_count, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
```

But how would I do that when I am actually creating the Factory, such as:

```
Factory.create(:user, :posts << ??)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a block like this:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user) do |user|
  FactoryGirl.create_list(:post, 10, user: user)
end
```